# What is "delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')"

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, heredoc

I am trying to execute following lines-

```
   sh """
      #!/bin/bash
      cd ${WORKSPACE}

      cat << EOF > build.sh
      #!/bin/bash
      mkdir wsbuildlinux
      cd wsbuildlinux
      cmake3 ../../wiresharkbuild_linux
      make
      EOF

      chmod 755 build.sh

      # run container and build wireshark
      ./build-env/run-wireshark-env ./build.sh
    """
```

and here is the content of "**build.sh**"-

```
  #!/bin/bash
  mkdir wsbuildlinux
  cd wsbuildlinux
  cmake3 ../../wiresharkbuild_linux
  make
  EOF

  chmod 755 build.sh

  # run container and build wireshark
  ./build-env/run-wireshark-env ./build.sh
```

But I keep getting following error-

```
/opt/cvsdirs/crdbuilds/jenkins/slave/workspace/Wireshark_Wireshark_trunk@tmp/durable-f510f070/script.sh: line 17: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

I have no idea what this error means and how to resolve it. Could you please give some advice on this

Comment: `EOF` has to be at the beginning of the line, not indented.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it, I have to keep it inside the "sh" to make it work right??

Comment: Yes, but get rid of the spaces at the beginning of that line.

Comment: Or use a `<<-` style heredoc (which allows hard tabs for indentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EOF` token has to be at the beginning of the line.

```
sh """
      #!/bin/bash
      cd ${WORKSPACE}

      cat << EOF > build.sh
      #!/bin/bash
      mkdir wsbuildlinux
      cd wsbuildlinux
      cmake3 ../../wiresharkbuild_linux
      make
EOF

      chmod 755 build.sh

      # run container and build wireshark
      ./build-env/run-wireshark-env ./build.sh
    """
```

Comment: I still got the same error, I got rid of the space from the front of it

Comment: The error message says the problem is in `script.sh`, not `build.sh`.

Comment: wait I just got it Thank you soooooooooooooooooooo Much you're a life saver